# How to convert a PyTorch Geometric Heterogenous Graph to a NetworkX graph for visualization?

Tags: python, pytorch, networkx, pytorch-geometric

I have a hetero data object that I have built with PyG, with node features and multiple node/edge types. I want to visualize it through NetworkX but the only function I can find is `tonetworkx` which only supports the regular data object, not the hetero type. How can I visualize my graph?